# ADO Rest API to query the current deployed release id?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there an ADO Rest API which let me to query the "currently deployed" release id of a release definition?

I tried to look in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1, but I only find a call to list all release. I am look for the one which is currently deployed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check out [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api to get the currently deployed release id.

You can use the query parameters to query the currently deployed release id of a specific stage of a specific release pipeline.

See below example: Using additional parameters `definitionId`,`deploymentStatus`,`definitionEnvironmentId`(ig.stage id.),`$top`

```
`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/org/proj/_apis/release/deployments?definitionId=3&deploymentStatus=succeeded&definitionEnvironmentId=5&$top=1&api-version=6.1-preview.2`
```

Note: You can get the `definitionId`, `definitionEnvironmentId` from the url of the releae pipeline.

[image]

If you are using powershell script to call above rest api. You need to escape the `$` in `$top` parameter by adding a back tick "`$top".

Comment: This only fetches the most recent deployment, which isn't necessarily currently deployed.

Answer (score 1):

Levi's response only returns the most recent deployment, which may not be what is currently deployed.

You can get the currently deployed Release Id from the Release Pipeline Definition.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get

The relevant path is .environments[].currentRelease.id

To check which environment that is referencing use .environments[].name

So for example, if have an environment named "PROD" and you've saved the output of the REST call to definition.json you could use jq to fetch the Release Id like this:

`cat definition.json | jq '.environments[] | select(.name == "PROD").currentRelease.id'`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Rest API for this purpose.

You can just query the [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---release) `Release.ReleaseId`:

> The identifier of the current release record.
>
> Example: 118